# mongoexport - export in ISO data format

Tags: mongodb, isodate, mongoexport

I am trying to export data from Mongodb where date is stored in ISO format.
Eg -

```
    {
    "_id" : "abcdef",
    "log" : [
        {
            "ts" : ISODate("2015-05-14T17:21:51Z"),
            "visitorId" : NumberLong(219301285)
        },
        {
            "ts" : ISODate("2015-05-15T19:20:52Z")
        }
    ],
    "uts" : ISODate("2015-05-14T17:21:50.589Z")
}
```

When I wrote the export command as

```
mongoexport --host localhost:27018 --db mydb --collection mycoll --query '{"log.ts":{$gte :new Date(1431619200000)}}'
--out test_1.json
```

It give me results in JSON format, but the date format is Numeric

```
    {
    "_id": "abcdef",
    "log": [
        {
            "ts": {
                "$date": 1431624111000
            },
            "visitorId": 219301285
        },
        {
            "ts": {
                "$date": 1431667764000
            },
            "visitorId": 0
        }
    ],
    "uts": {
        "$date": 1431624110589
    }
}
```

What I want is date should be in ISO Format and not numeric.

How can I do that?

I tried using below format, but it doesn't work and gives error

```
mongoexport --host localhost:27018 --db mydb --collection mycoll --query "{'log.ts':{'$gte' :{'$date':'2015-05-15 10:00:00.000Z'}}}" --out test_1.json
```

Comment: FWIW, given you example, both your initial query as well as the one given as an answer below work for me using MongoDB 3.0.2. And both output the date as a string `{"_id":"abcdef","log":[{"ts":{"$date":"2015-05-14T17:21:51.000Z"},"visitorId":{"$numberLong":"219301285"}},{"ts":{"$date":"2015-05-15T19:20:52.000Z"}}],"uts":{"$date":"2015-05-14T17:21:50.589Z"}}` Is this issue localized to pre-3.0 version ?

Answer (score 2):

`mongoexport` produces [strict mode JSON](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) as its output. With that format, date are represented as `{ "$date": "<date>" }` but the representation of `<date>` is not homogeneous among MongoDB versions:

- Starting with [MongoDB 2.6](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#date) (to quote the doc):
  *" `<date>` is an ISO-8601 date format with a mandatory time zone field following the template `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.mmm<+/-Offset>`."*
- Up to [MongoDB 2.4](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#date), date was represented as *"64-bit signed integer for milliseconds since epoch UTC (unsigned before version 1.9.1)."*

---

If you want the "new" ISO date representation directly from `mongoexport` you will have to update to MongoDB 2.6 at least. Otherwise you will have either:

- to post-process you data using your favorite script language
- *or* to patch (backport?) the change from 2.6 to 2.4

None of them being long-term solution, as of myself I would strongly push toward updating MongoDB (up to >=3.0). But as you understand it, this may lead to some compatibility issues. So YMMV.

Answer (score -1):

I solved with following query mongo 2.6.12:

> mongoexport --username blabla --password --db bmv4 --collection appointment --query '{created: {$gte: new Date(1472680800000)}},$or:[{action:"CREA"},{action:"CREV"},{action:"MOVE"},{action:"DELETE"},{action:"FREE"}]}' --out bmv4Appointments.json

I found the solution [here](http://buraktas.com/mongoexport-query-with-using-date/)